# Is my "Games for Windows Marketplace" ID the same as my Windows Live ID?

Tags: games-for-windows-live

I am able to sign in on xbox live and hotmail using the same credentials I am entering in the "games for windows marketplace" application. However, I get an error code 80048882 with the details being `Exception of type 'Microsoft.GamesForWindows.XLiveServices.LiveIdWrapper.IDCRLException' was thrown.` I have added the application to my firewall. Any ideas what causes this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the problem was, but it went away after I switched to my home network. I was earlier behind a corporate firewall(which closes everything except port 80, i think) and a proxy. Not sure what was responsible, but it seems the error was due to connectivity problems.

Answer (score 1):

For error:

`Exception of type 'Microsoft.GamesForWindows.XLiveServices.LiveIdWrapper.IDCRLException' was thrown.`

Type

```
netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
```

in the Command Prompt shell, and then press the Enter key and restart the PC.

> **Warning** The netsh int ip reset command
>   will reset all IP information, default
>   gateway information, and DNS server
>   information. Before you restart the
>   computer after you run this command,
>   you must configure your TCP/IP
>   settings. Otherwise, you may not be
>   able to connect to the computer
>   remotely.

An addendum to the solution: Add the games exe to your Firewall exclusions list (Win XP/ Win Vista), and forward the following ports:

UDP 88

UDP 3074